# AngularJS Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get a date value. Whenever the the checkbox is unchecked and the date picker is invisible I am getting the error that : 'Cannot read property 'NTLI' of undefined'. if the check box is checked and the date picker is visible everything works fine

```
<md-checkbox ng-model="user.NTLI" layout="row" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid">
  NTLI
</md-checkbox>
<div ng-show="user.NTLI">
<fieldset class="standard">
    <legend>NTLI</legend>
    <md-input-container>
        <label>Efective date</label>
        <md-datepicker ng-model="user.efectiveDateNTLI"></md-datepicker>
    </md-input-container>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

```
var efDate = '';
if ($scope.user.NTLI != undefined) 
{
    efDate = $scope.user.efectiveDateNTLI
}
```

Comment: In your controller, make it so user.NTLI = false;, you get this error because it doesn't exist.

Comment: Do you have anywhere in your app which is bound to user itself?

Comment: One suggestion(little off topic) :  leave the habit of writing `{` on next line. It should be on same line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have user defined,

```
$scope.user ={};
if ($scope.user.NTLI != undefined) 
{
    efDate = $scope.user.efectiveDateNTLI
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is initial value if your `user` object? You need it initialized first to be accessible from `$scope`.

```
$scope.user = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

As `user` is not available it shows `undefined` when reading property of it. Just add following:

`$scope.user = {};`

in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Assign `user = {}` on `ng-init`

like

```
<div ng-init="user = {}"> 
...
..//code
...
</div>
```

But other answers are also correct.